# Listagem de domínios a partir dos cookies

Tags: php, javascript

É possível obter com php ou JavaScript uma listagem de todos os domínios dos cookies armazenados no navegador do usuário?

Answer (score 0):

Sua pergunta é vaga, você nem ao menos tentou fazer para a gente te ajudar baseado em algo?

Em todo caso, talvez isso te ajude para pegar os `cookies` da página.

```
function obter_cookies() {

var cookies = { };

if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
    var split = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
        var name_value = split[i].split("=");
        name_value[0] = name_value[0].replace(/^ /, '');
        cookies[decodeURIComponent(name_value[0])] = decodeURIComponent(name_value[1]);
    }
}
return cookies;
}
```